# OOP: Designing a tree, dividing functionality between Node class and a Tree Class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I need to implement a custom tree class (using C++). Throughout my work I've seen many tree implementations. Some implemented a "super Node" class which was exposed to the user. An instance of which (root node) acted as the tree. Some exposed a tree class, which utilized a node class to construct a tree. Some used the node class as a pure data struct, leaving functionality such as tree construction to the tree class. Others put the construction - like node.Split(), into the node class.

Say you needed to design a binary tree (like a KD-tree). What would be the "best" approach from OOP perspective. Have node class just contain the data, or the logic to split itself into children? How much logic in general should a node class contain?

Thanks ahead for constructive input!

Comment: I like the Java approach for TreeSet/TreeMap where the fact that it's tree is an implementation detail and it exposes traversal and mutate methods that hide the internals.

Comment: 'What would be the "best" approach from OOP perspective.' -- Such questions are too vague, as the notion of best is hard to nail down in design. It depends on what is going to change. OOP designs often facilitate adding new classes somewhere without breaking other classes (open-closed principle). Also, what level of details do the users of the class need? Encapsulation is key, but it depends on what your clients are doing. It's hard to design something well if you can't know how it's going to be used (what the clients need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one OOP rule you should always follow,

> Every class represents an entity. Classes have properties and methods
>   i.e. the attributes of the entities and it's behaviour

So you need to follow your understanding of the scenario.

Here's how I look at a node.
It has some data, a right node reference and a left node reference. I don't think a node should be able to do anything except provide you with the data so I would write a node class something like this:

```
class Node
{
public:
    int Data;    // yeah, you would obviously use templates, so it's not restricted to a particular type

    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;

    // also you can write constructors and maybe some sort of cast operator overload to be able to make the 

    // we could also make it return the subtree itself
    getRightSubTree(){ return Tree(*Right); }
    getLeftSubTree(){ return Tree(*Left); }
};
```

A Tree should be like this then.

```
class Tree
{
private:
    Node root;
public:
    Tree(Node t):root(t){} // every tree should have a root. Cannot be null.

    // since the root node will be able to handle the tree structure, now we'll need the necessary methods
    void addNode(Node n){
    // code here
    }
    ....


    getSubTree(int data){
        // check if node with that data exists and all
        ...
        Node n = getNode(data);
        return Tree(n);
    }
};
```

Okay so I think you've got an idea now. It's all about how you look at the system.

Comment: The confusion with trees is that you can say things like "every subtree is also a tree," so the distinction between tree and node isn't clear.

Comment: so what I would do is, add a subtree function that'll return a tree with the given node as the root.  
I'd go for that approach because I build the tree as one tree with many nodes
Anyone who requires subtrees, will however get them too